# ORACLE convert number to string

Tags: oracle, to-char

Need some help in converting numbers:

```
select to_char(a, '99D99')
       , to_char(a, '90D99')
from
(
select 50 a from dual
union
select 50.57 from dual
union
select 5.57 from dual
union
select 0.35 from dual
union
select 0.4 from dual
```

Will result in:

```
1      ,35    0,35
2      ,40    0,40
3     5,57    5,57
4    50,00   50,00
5    50,57   50,57
```

But how to make my output like:

1. 0,35
2. 0,4
3. 5,57
4. 50
5. 50,57

I need `0` before comma, but not after.

Comment: You can use `90D99`, but that would make your second value as `0,4` rather than `0,40`. I'm not sure you can have one model that allows both `0,40` and `50`.

Comment: 90D99 gives same 0.40 to me. 0.40 was my mistake...i need 0,4 ofc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the [`FM` format model modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#sthref456) to get close, as you won't get the trailing zeros after the decimal separator; but you will still get the separator itself, e.g. `50.`. You can use `rtrim` to get rid of that:

```
select to_char(a, '99D90'),
    to_char(a, '90D90'),
    to_char(a, 'FM90D99'),
    rtrim(to_char(a, 'FM90D99'), to_char(0, 'D'))
from (
    select 50 a from dual
    union all select 50.57 from dual
    union all select 5.57 from dual
    union all select 0.35 from dual
    union all select 0.4 from dual
)
order by a;

TO_CHA TO_CHA TO_CHA RTRIM(
------ ------ ------ ------
   .35   0.35 0.35   0.35
   .40   0.40 0.4    0.4
  5.57   5.57 5.57   5.57
 50.00  50.00 50.    50
 50.57  50.57 50.57  50.57
```

Note that I'm using `to_char(0, 'D')` to generate the character to trim, to match the decimal separator - so it looks for the same character, `,` or `.`, as the first `to_char` adds.

The slight downside is that you lose the alignment. If this is being used elsewhere it might not matter, but it does then you can also wrap it in an `lpad`, which starts to make it look a bit complicated:

```
...
lpad(rtrim(to_char(a, 'FM90D99'), to_char(0, 'D')), 6)
...

TO_CHA TO_CHA TO_CHA RTRIM( LPAD(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(A,'FM
------ ------ ------ ------ ------------------------
   .35   0.35 0.35   0.35     0.35
   .40   0.40 0.4    0.4       0.4
  5.57   5.57 5.57   5.57     5.57
 50.00  50.00 50.    50         50
 50.57  50.57 50.57  50.57   50.57
```

Comment: rtrim(to_char(a, 'FM90D99'), to_char(0, 'D'))    is  perfect thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
select replace(to_char(a, '90D90'),'.00','')
from
(
select 50 a from dual
union
select 50.57 from dual
union
select 5.57 from dual
union
select 0.35 from dual
union
select 0.4 from dual
);
```

Give a look also as this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9562) for test.

Comment: It was my mistake. i need 0.4. so we can use trim...but as for mee it is too complex...rtrim(rtrim(to_char(a, '90D99'), '0'), ',')